# I have problems connecting to the second database it gves false positive saying its conected but it does that even wen i give blank credentials

Tags: node.js, database, api, express, nodes

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import sql from "mssql";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
const secretKey = 'secret';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

const dbConfig = {
  server: '192.168.100.180',
  user: 'sa',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'database',
  options: {
    encrypt: false,
    enableArithAbort: false,
  },
};


const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

sql.connect(dbConfig)
  .then(() => console.log("Database connected!"))
  .catch((err) => console.error("Error connecting to database: ", err));
 
  app.get("/api/get", authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
    const search = req.query.search;
    const njesia = req.user.njesia;
    let sifraArt;
  
    try {
      const result = await sql.query(
        `SELECT distinct K.nom,S.Sifra_OE, O.ImeOrg, S.Sifra_Art,  K.imeart, S.Cena
        FROM Soart S 
        INNER JOIN OrgEd O ON S.Sifra_OE = O.Sifra_OE
        INNER JOIN KatArt K ON S.Sifra_Art = K.Sifra_Art
        FULL OUTER JOIN ABarKod A ON K.Sifra_Art = A.Sifra_Art
        WHERE (S.Sifra_Art = '${search}'  OR K.nom = '${search}' OR A.nom = '${search}') AND S.Sifra_OE = ${njesia};
        `
      );
      console.log("result:", result);
  
      if (result.recordset.length > 0) {
        sifraArt = result.recordset[0].Sifra_Art;
        console.log("sifraArt:", sifraArt);
        console.log("result:", result);
  
        // Query the kasa database using the poolArka property on req.user object
        const resultKasa = await req.user.poolArka.request().query(`
          SELECT   CenaOsn , Nom , ImeArt , Sifra_Art  from ArkaKat
          WHERE Sifra_Art = '${sifraArt}'
        `);
        console.log("CenaOsn:", resultKasa.recordset[0].CenaOsn);
        console.log("Nom:", resultKasa.recordset[0].Nom);
  
        console.log("resultKasa:", resultKasa);
        res.send(result);
      } else {
        res.send(result);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send("An error occurred while fetching data");
    }
  });
  
  
//INNER JOIN ABarKod A ON A.Sifra_Art = S.Sifra_Art
//OR A.ABarBroj='${search}'
app.post("/api/register", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { username, password, njesia, arkak } = req.body;
    const result = await sql.query`INSERT INTO Users (username, password, njesia, arkak) VALUES (${username}, ${password}, ${njesia}, ${arkak})`;
    res.send("User registered successfully");
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});

app.post("/api/login", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const result = await sql.query`SELECT  username, password, njesia, arkak FROM Users WHERE username = ${username}`;
    if (result.recordset.length === 0) {
      res.status(401).send("Invalid username or password");
      return;
    }
    const user = result.recordset[0];
    if (user.password !== password) {
      res.status(401).send("Invalid username or password");
      return;
    }
    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id, njesia: user.njesia, arkak: user.arkak }, secretKey ,  );
    res.send({ token });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});

app.get("/api/protected", authenticateToken, (req, res) => {
  const { njesia, arkak } = req.user;
  res.send(`This is a protected endpoint. User's njesia is ${njesia} and arkak is ${arkak}`);
});

async function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  if (token == null) {
    return res.sendStatus(401);
  }
  jwt.verify(token, secretKey, async (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.sendStatus(403);
    }
    req.user = user;
    try {
      // Connect to the kasa database
      const dbConfigArka = {
        server: user.arkak,
        user: 'sa',
        password: '',
        database: '',
        options: {
          encrypt: true,
          enableArithAbort: false,
        },
      };
      const poolArka = await sql.connect(dbConfigArka);
      console.log(`Connected to database ${dbConfigArka.database} at ${dbConfigArka.server}`); 
      req.user.poolArka = poolArka;
      next();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }
  });
}

app.listen(5001, () => console.log("API is working!"));
```

i want the query to run in the first database and that works retrive the result get the sifra_art and put it in the second query but the problem is that i get blank data in the second query and i belive the second database is not connecting at all the console log gives me connection everytime even if i intentionaly give bad credentials